# inversion list for python

Tags: python, data-structures, libraries, python-2.x

Is there a pure python implementation of [inversion lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_list), ideally in the base libraries?

> an inversion list is a data structure that describes a set of non-overlapping numeric ranges, stored in increasing order.
>
> The set is stored in an array. Every other element is the first element of a range, and every other element is the first element after that range (a half-open range).
>
> For example, for ranges 10-14, 25-37, the inversion list would be:
>
> ```
> 10 15 25 38
> ```
>
> To search whether an item belongs to any of the ranges, a binary search is made. If the search ends in a "first" element, the searched item is in the set. If the search ends in an "after" element, or outside the array, the searched item is not in the set.
>
> This data structure is used in many Unicode implementations for storing Unicode character ranges

PyICU's UnicodeSet seems to use SWIGGed in C libraries.

Comment: This seems really easy to implement yourself with the `bisect` module.